# C# QuikGraph Sort elements by Graph Hiarachie

Tags: c#, .net, graph

I am using a BidirectionalGraph from QuikGraph to build a directed graph. Here is an example of a graph:

```
     CityA
     /   \
  CityB   CityC
     \   /    \
     CityD   CityE
```

Now I get an unsorted list of cities. I now want to sort this list according to the hierarchy in the graph.

Example:

```
SortCities(["CityC", "CityA", "CityB", "CityD"]) // Returns "CityA", "CityB", "CityC", "CityD"
```

Comment: Hello, is this homework ?

Comment: No, it isn’t! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently had a similar problem. QuikGraph provides the algorithm [Topological Sort](https://github.com/KeRNeLith/QuikGraph/wiki/Topological-Sort). This sorts your graph (top-to-bottom, left-to-right).

Probably your solution would look like this:

```
    public List<string> SortCities(List<string> citieList)
    {
        List<string> sortedCities = new List<string>();
        foreach (var vertex in _graph.TopologicalSort()) // Iterates over your vertexes (top-to-bottom, left-to-right)
        {
            if (citieList.Contains(vertex.Name))
            {
                sortedCities.Add(vertex.Name);
                citieList.Remove(vertex.Name);
            }
        }
        return sortedCities;
    }
```

Note: This is probably not the most efficient solution, especially for very large graphs it leads to quite a lot of overhead.